# Python multiprocessing with unrelated processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing, sockets

I have many processes that are spawned separately, not from parent to child. The processes need to send a message to *specific* processes. The receiving processes address (pid) can be stored in a database, but the processes cannot share any common variables in memory.

I could not find any way to accomplish this with pythons multiprocess package and am now looking into a socket-based server, but this issue still left me curious if this kind of architecture could be achieved with multiprocessing - the advantage would be to easily pass pickable objects.

Comment: did you ever find a solution here? I *want* the semantics of multiprocessing so I want to be able to look up the queue handles, so to speak

Answer (score 2):

> The processes need to send a message to specific processes. The receiving processes address (pid) can be stored in a database, but the processes cannot share any common variables in memory.

Database?  Why?  Everyone uses a file for this, since a file is cheap, available, and you're only storing one integer value.

Also.  Since you're going to use a file, you have more interesting choices.

1. Every process writes the message to a named pipe.  The receiving process takes requests off the named pipe.
2. Every process writes the message to a file.  A simple lock assures that only one process at a time has access to the file, assuring serialization.  The receiving process reads from this file.
3. Every process uses HTTP to make a RESTful request to the receiving process.  The receiving process uses a stripped-down HTTP server framework to process requests.
4. Every process uses a message queue to enqueue messages.  The receiving process dequeues the messages.  The queue is a file.

etc.  And yes, there are more.  But they start to get OS-specific.